# On running code on server it prompts to 404 page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying my hands on JAVA Spring MVC by writing a hello world code. I browsed a lot for it and I am trying to run it but I am not able to do that. Here is the following code:

HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.mvc" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

   <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HelloController.java

```
package com.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController{

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String printHello(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Hello Spring MVC Framework!");

  return "hello";
 }

}
```

WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the screenshot of the libraries used:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvrfr.jpg)

Everything seems fine with the code with no errors but when I run this on the server then it prompts to HTTP Status: 404 error with description "the requested resource is not available".Kindly seek me some way out of this.

I am getting the following error in the server console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet /SpringBlog threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Mar 07, 2016 2:25:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'HelloWeb'
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:01 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet     initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'HelloWeb': initialization started
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:01 PM   org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'HelloWeb-servlet': startup date [Mon Mar 07 14:25:01 COT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:01 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-   INF/HelloWeb-servlet.xml]
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler 'helloController'
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'helloController'
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/hello/] onto handler 'helloController'
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'HelloWeb': initialization completed in 817 ms
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 07, 2016 2:25:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9007 ms
```

Comment: What url you are hitting on the browser ?

Comment: You have to go to `http://localhost:<port>/hello`.  Also this is a little bit outdated. Try spring boot - http://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: url: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/
I am doing it through Eclipse IDE. SpringMVC is my project name. I ran the program on Apache Tomcat Server through the IDE. It is directing me to the url "http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/".

I also tried http://localhost:8080/hello but it is not working.

Comment: The web app context is `/SpringMVC`(each webapp deployed on tomcat has its own context path). Inside this app context, the only mapping you have is for `/hello`. So the complete path is `http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/hello`

Comment: Thanks.JB Nizet. It worked for me now. I think I need to brush up my spring concepts more.